# How do I change my logname?

Tags: users

How do I change my logname?For e.g: xyz@ubuntu in the terminal how do I change xyz? I have tried this command

```
usermod -l *newname* -d /home/*newname* -m *oldname*
```

but that gave me an error user xyz is currently used by process PID

Command line solutions are appreciated.

Comment: You cannot create a user with the same name as an existing user - you can list the all of current users with `cat /etc/passwd`.

Comment: you want to remove the "hostname". Ex. `braiam@braiam-pc` becomes `braiam`?

Comment: user wants to change `xyz` in `xyz@ubuntu`, @Braiam. It might also be simpler to create a new user with `useradd <newname>`, and move the user home directory with `mv /home/<oldname> /home/<newname>`, though it might not work due to user specific files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to not be logged in as the user whose name you are trying to change, while running the `usermod` command to change the user name. You will have to log out, log in as a different user (such as `root`), and run the command without your standard user being logged in.